# How to solve this integral equation? (if possible using functional analysis)

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

I have the following integral equation:
$$u(x)=1+2 \int_{0}^{\pi} u(t) \cos (x+t) d t,$$
and I need to solve it for $u$, this is an exercise from my course of functional analysis, but I have never seen before an integral equation, and I have no idea how to approach this. Can you help me here?

Comment: Are you interesting in finding such a function $u$, or just proving the existence of one?

Comment: Finding $u$, I think that is what the exercise asks for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$u''(x) = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi} u(t) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \cos (x+t) dt =-2 \int_{0}^{\pi} u(t)  \cos (x+t) dt =-u(x)+1$$

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(u(x)-1) = -u(x)+1 $$
The solution will be
$$u(x) = 1 + a \sin(x)+b\cos(x)$$
with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Is not $u''(x)=1-u(x)?$

Comment: No, I think $u''(x)= u(x)-1 $

Comment: Note that $cos''=-cos$

Comment: Yes, indeed $u''(x)= -u(x)+1$, I just correct the error. Thank you.